# How to identify data type from opcode?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, opcode

Suppose I have the following bytes in the `.data` segment of a PE file opened in IDA:

```
32 A2 DF 2D 99 2B 00 00  CD 5D 20 D2 66 D4 FF FF
01 00 D2 8B 0A 35 60 BD  F1 C9 D6 5D 6C 59 51 D5
24 FD 02 F5 43 26 29 79  53 3E B0 FB 2B 97 BF 5E
```

I was wondering how do I identify the data type from above (i.e., INT, Floating-point, etc.).

By the look of it, you could tell it is not a string since it contain bytes that are not in ASCII table, unless it is Unicode characters.

I tried to create a C program containing floating-points and integers with different values to see if there is a pattern defining the data type, but unfortunately, I couldn't find any pattern. The bytes completely change when you change the floating-point value.

I was wondering if you could help how do we identify the data type from above?

Comment: I would look at the .text section and see how the memory gets accessed.

Comment: There are some tell-tale signs.  For example, seeing sequential `FF`s make me think that there's a negative number being stored.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if you could help how do we identify the data type from above?

In general, you can't.

For all you know this is a string of random bytes used to seed some PRNG, or a public key used to verify some signature, or a part of compressed ASCII string.

Only if you know something about the program can you make some guesses.

Comment: how could you tell "used to seed some PRNG, or a public key", based on the look of the bytes? just wondering

Comment: @neehack You _can't_ (which is the whole point of this answer).